# cannot convert from DenseInstance to Instance

Tags: java, eclipse, instance, weka

My code shows the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert DenseInstance to Instance"

I have installed weka 3.7 jar library and still the error shows.

Instance instance = new DenseInstance(13);

Please, can someone help if I am installing the right library or not? I tried with weka 3.8 jar library. The error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was having more than one library of weka installed in my project. So I removed the previous versions and kept only the latest one.